# Are you able to interpret the word '' in '' at this paragraph?

Tags: grammar, orthography

Paragraph :
They found that people were more honest when they were watched by eyes than when there were pictures of flowers. They put times as much money in.

[image: Scan of the handwritten paragraph with the word 'in' highlighted]

Comment: The previous paragraph says "The scientists monitored an honesty box" (a box in which people put payments for small purchases without anyone supervising).  So "in" means "in the box".

Comment: So some would say it remains a preposition, now intransitive.